# How to load libraries into controllers and how to dynamically load app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails. I came from a Codeigniter background. I am having a hard time finding resources on Rails 3.0 for beginners. I read my new Rails book but am still confused about a few things.

How do I include my libraries or helpers into a controller? Do I use an "include" or "require"?

The 2nd question is how do I dynamically load plugins? Let say I have 1,000 plugins. I don't want them to be all initialized. Is there a way to controller which plugin are initialized from controllers?

Answer (score 2):

When your app starts it will run all the scripts in `yourapp/config/initializers`, there you can add some stuff that you want always present.

in `yourapp/config/application.rb` you can add

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

inside the `class Application` declaration.
Then any time you use a class it doesn't know about like `SomeNewClass.new "param"` rails will try to autoload `yourapp/lib/some_new_class.rb`

As for your second question I don't know. I have never used more than a few plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike PHP (Codeigniter), in Ruby `require` and `include` are very different in behaviour.
`require` loads a given path (somewhat like PHP) while `include` is usually used to include a `Module` in a `Class`.

`require` is a method from `Kernel` while `include` acts more like an object of class `Class`. Try -

```
Kernel.respond_to? :require
include.is_a? Class
```

Before jumping on Rails, I suggest you to read on Ruby. I suggest [this book](http://www.google.com/books?q=isbn:0596516177) and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_programming_language.

For Ruby on Rails, I recommend -

1. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/
2. http://api.rubyonrails.org/

For 2nd question,
I guess, initialising plugins is part of Rails' initialisation process, so it probably can not be *selective* (but I'm not sure). See http://ryanbigg.com/guides/initialization.html for more information.

The most easiest way to avoid a plugin from being initialised is to put it in some path which is not in Rails' `(auto)load_paths`, say `vendor/extensions` and `require` them in controllers when needed using

```
require "vendor/extensions/example-plugin/lib/example-plugin"
```

However, I recommend against it and suggest to wait until your plugin count reaches 1000/10. :)